# Как получить ключ в Dictionary зная порядковый номер элемента?

Tags: c#, словари

Пример:

```
 Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 dictionary.Add(3, "black");
 dictionary.Add(4, "word");
 dictionary.Add(5, "end");
 //здесь нет ошибки
 string value = dictionary[1];
 //а вот здесь ошибка
 //нужно получить ключ по номеру элемента
 int key = dictionary[1].key;
```

если же мы обращаемся по циклу foreach то все получается

```
//а вот так работает
int i = 0;
foreach (var var in dictionary)
{
    if (i == 1)
    key = var.Key;
    i++;
 }
```

Но мне надо менять коллекцию поэтому могу обращаться только через for
Как это сделать?

Comment: `Dictionary` это неупорядоченная коллекция, поэтому ваша задача бессмысленна.

Comment: *здесь нет ошибки* - как раз будет ошибка во время исполнения, потому что такого ключа нет в словаре

Comment: @АндрейNOP изменил условие

Comment: *а вот так работает* - это бред, потому что, если вы добавите в словарь еще элементов или удалите что-то из него, то порядок перебора через `foreach` изменится. Усвойте это **Dictionary неупорядоченная коллекция**

Comment: Возможно вам нужно что-то вроде [OrderedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx). С обычным же словарем задача некорректна.

Comment: @АндрейNOP про OrderedDictionary кстати забыл, имхо вполне себе хорошее решение. А Dictionary по сути упорядочен же, только на механизм этого упорядочивания я бы не надеялся, можно и колено себе прострелить)))

Comment: @yolosora, откуда упорядоченность, если там хеш-таблица? Минус же `OrderedDictionary` в том, что это не дженерик (не помню есть дженерик-аналог в BCL).

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну как я понимаю порядок как таковой есть, но он не определен

Comment: Возможно автору надо использовать просто `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`, если ему нужен именно доступ по индексу, а не по ключу (или `List<MyClass>`).

Comment: @yolosora, порядок есть, но он меняется при каждом добавлении/удалении элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Здесь нет ошибки" - это неправда, попробуйте запустить ваш код, поймаете исключение.

А решить задачу можно с помощью Linq, например.

```
 Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 dictionary.Add(3, "black");
 dictionary.Add(4, "word");
 dictionary.Add(5, "end");
 var value = dictionary.ElementAt(1).Value;
 var key = dictionary.ElementAt(1).Key;
```